# FromSqlRaw : Cannot create a DbSet for 'Model' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have defined a Model class with 2 attributes `[keyless]` and `[NotMapped]` to map with a Stored procedure written in database. I have also defined the below line in my ModelContext class

```
public DbSet<sp_MySP> sp_MySP { get; set; }
```

When executing the SP using the below line, I am getting the error "Cannot create a DbSet for 'sp_MySP' because this type is not included in the model for the context"

```
var data= _context.Set<sp_MySP>().FromSqlRaw("EXEC sp_MySP {0}", id).ToList();
```

2 questions -

1. How to solve this error.
2. Is there a way to not define the model class in modelcontext and use the SP using FromSqlRaw?

I am using EF Core7.0 and .net 6.0

Comment: Why `[NotMapped]`? It is mapped.

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  I just want to create model class for my SP, do I need to define it in context class for being able to Set ?

Comment: It is required to tell EF that class has mapping. You can do that explicitly in `OnModelConfiguring` or making public DbSet property in `DbContext`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv so, in order to use _context.Set<> we need to define a Model class with keyless and also define it int context class. And there is not other way for the same. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, right now EF Core builds mapping once per `DbContext` class type and it's options. Trying to use not registered class later will fail.